On bounded implying totally bounded; Gamelin and Greene
I am reading a proof in Gamelin and Greene's book on topology of the fact that if $E\subset\mathbb R^n$ is bounded, then it is totally bounded. The proof goes like this (slightly paraphrasing):

Since $E$ is bounded, $E\subset T=[-b,b]^n$ for some $b>0$, and it suffices to prove that $T$ is totally bounded, as any subspace of a totally bounded space is totally bounded. For this, let $\epsilon>0$. Then the balls $B(\epsilon j,\epsilon)$ cover $T$, where $j=(j_1,\ldots,j_n)$ ranges over all integral lattice points of $\mathbb R^n$ which satisfy $\epsilon |j_i|\leq 2b$, $1\leq i\leq n$ (recall, an integral lattice point is a point whose coordinates are integers). Since there are only finitely many such lattice points, $T$ is totally bounded.

I am slightly confused over why the balls $B(\epsilon j,\epsilon)$ would cover $T$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, the vector $\frac{\epsilon}{2}(1, 1,\ldots, 1)$ will be a distance $\geq \sqrt{n}\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ away from each vector of the form $\epsilon j$ where $j$ is a point on the integer lattice. So for $n\geq 4$ it won't belong to any ball of the form $B(\epsilon j, \epsilon)$. It seems to me this is an error in the book, and I don't know how to correct it.
Grateful for any comments and answers that can amend this proof.

If $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equipped with the standard Euclidean metric, then you are correct that there is an error.  To fix this error, we take balls $B(\frac\epsilon{\sqrt{n}}j,\epsilon)$ where $j=(j_1,\cdots,j_n)$ ranges over the lattice points which satisfy $\frac\epsilon{\sqrt{n}}|j_i|\leq b$ for all $i$.
Then any point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is less than distance $\sqrt{n}$ from a lattice point, so any point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is less than distance $\epsilon$ from $\frac\epsilon{\sqrt{n}}j$, where $j$ is a lattice point.
Alternatively, it is possible that the authors are working with the $l^\infty$ metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$, in which case their argument is valid.
